# How to open a layer in QGIS from another application?

Tags: qgis, metadata

Let's say I have some metadata about a layer stored in some custom application, and I would like to open or view the layer in QGIS.

What, if any, are my options?

Edit: formats include shp, wms, wfs, geotiff.

Comment: Which layer format would you like to open? Your question should be more accurate to be able to help...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to call a python script to open QGIS and add a layer, the general code logic would go something like this:

```
import os, time
from qgis.core import *

os.startfile('C:/Program Files/QGIS Brighton/bin/qgis.bat')
time.sleep(30) # sleep script for 30sec to wait for QGIS to open

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/path/to/shapefile/file.shp", "layer_name_you_like", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call QGIS and pass the layer

`qgis yourlayer.shp`

that will load QGIS and load the layer.