# QGIS, add a layer (shapefile) to a running QGIS from an external application

Tags: qgis, python, layers

I'm trying to load a shapefile as a new layer into a running QGIS application using python within a Windows command shell.  The python is basically what is explained in this post:

[How to open a layer in QGIS from another application?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141976/how-to-open-a-layer-in-qgis-from-another-application)

I have worked through various errors and now I get none, but the layer does not appear in my QGIS.  And I get no feedback.  I can drag the shapefile onto the map and it renders fine.  I'm using QGIS 2.0.1.

I don't know if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.  Can I communicate with a running QGIS using the mechanism described?